How do I make my code to make display values with a string on each output?
Hello I am a python fresher and I am looking for some extra help.
CODE SNIPPET:
def cube(side):
  volume =  side **3
  surface_area = 6 * (side**2)
  return volume, surface_area
my_cube = cube(5) 
print(my_cube)

#output is 125,150
in the code above, I want the output to include a statement like:
"The volume is 125, and The surface area is 150"

Use f-strings every day... f-strings every day
Snippet:
def cube(side):
  volume, surface_area =  side **3, 6 * (side**2)
  return print(f"The volume is {volume}, and The surface area is {surface_area}")

cube(5) 

Output:
The volume is 125, and The surface area is 150
